# Variable greyed out in function in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to change the value of a variable inside a function

To make it easier to understand I'll name the first file File1 and the second File2
I assigned a value to a variable in File1 and I defined a function in File2 that should change the value of the variable when a certain event happens, but it never changes and instead the variable is greyed out in the function.
Am I doing something wrong or is it even possible to do such thing?

Edit: Here's a code sample:

```
File1:
global winner
winner = 0
player_1 = 0
player_2 = 0

File2:
def determine_winner(winner):
    if certain_event:
        winner = 1
    else:
        winner = 2
def winner_score(winner, player_1, player_2):
    if winner == 1:
        player_1 += 1
    elif winner == 2:
        player_2 += 1
```

This is a simplified version of my code, winner never changes value

Comment: Please post an example code sample. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: My guess is you forgot to use the `global` declaration in the function that changes the variable.

Comment: Also on a good programming habit note: don't name things "file1" and "file2", name things after what they're for/what they do/what they house (this goes for files, functions, variables, classes, etc.) While the interpreter doesn't care what you call things, _humans who need to read and understand code_ do, including you when you have to revisit your code at any point in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've added a code sample

Comment: `global` gets used inside the function to tell the function to access the global namespace for that variable instead of the function namespace. Using `global` in the global namespace does nothing

Comment: There's a good talk from a few years ago that explains why what you're doing doesn't work:  https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns

Answer (score 0):

If it is greyed out that usually means it is not being used. You are changing/assigning the value of a variable that isn't being used elsewhere in the code. For some reason you are creating a local variable within that function and you are not actually referencing the global variable that you want.

Id recommend checking out this link for what you are trying to do: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-import-variables-from-another-file-in-python/

Try returning the new value of winner in the function that modifies it:

```
def determine_winner(winner):
    if certain_event:
        winner = 1
    else:
        winner = 2
    return winner
```

and make sure when you call this function it looks something like:

```
file1.winner = determine_winner(file1.winner)
```

Or alternatively you can simply remove the parameter all together and modify the global variable directly in the function:

```
def determine_winner():
    if certain_event:
        file1.winner = 1
    else:
        file1.winner = 2
```

What is happening is you are correctly passing in the global variable as an argument, the issue is when you pass a variable into a function it is simply passing in the value and not an actual pointer to that data. So when you change the winner variable inside the function you are changing the value of the local winner variable. For the global winner variable to actually be changed you need to return the new value or just reference the global variable from inside the function instead of passing it into the function as an argument.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried making a global variable but still the same problem, I've just added a code sample perhaps that could help for better understanding

Comment: @KianFarrokhseresht I'm currently editing the answer hopefully this correctly fixes your problem

Answer (score 0):

It's greyed out because there is no reference between the two files for that variable `winner`.

Do this using classes instead and name your files like so:

- `File1.py` becomes `Player.py`
- `File2.py` becomes `Game.py`

Pseudo-ish code below:

Player.py

```py
class Player:
   def __init__(self):
       self.winner = False
```

Game.py:

```py
import Player # assumes they are in the same directory

def determine_winner(player_1, player_2):
    if certain_event:
        player_1.winner = True
    else:
        player_2.winner = True
    return player_1, player_2

def winner_score(player_1, player_2):
    if player_1.winner:
        player_1 += 1
    elif player_2.winner:
        player_2 += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # If you run the file, it's like you're "playing" the game
    player_1 = Player() # instantiate player 1
    player_2 = Player() # instantiate player 2 (could do more players too)

   # Game stuff
   player_1, player_2 = determine_winner(player_1, player_2)
   # etc...
```

I mean, I don't know what your goal is (there's other things that you could do to make this way better), but generally, you should be working with classes for this kind of stuff.